# How to select all data from specific tables for a given schema/prefix in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a muliti-tenant database structure where each tenant resides in a separate database.

So what I had wanted is to create a procedure that spools data of particular tables from all these databases having the same prefix.

**Below is the code i have but seems to result to what i want.**

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'm_appuser'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'mifostenant%'
```

Result of the above is as below;
[image: Result of the above]

Your kind help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could it be that your title would better written as: ***How to select all data from all tables for a given schema/prefix?*** Your current statement creates a generated list of `SELECT` statements that could be used to select the data. You would like to automate this second step. Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @John K. N. I think that's what I'm looking for. Your kind help on the same will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` as per this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276949/5059085).

This will allow you to [prepare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) all rows into one statement that you can execute.

Comment: Thanks for your kind contribution but it seemed not to sort out my problem. May be you can guide me further on how to apply the the GROUP_CONCAT in this same scenario. Thannks

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ';')
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'm_appuser' AND
> TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'mifostenant%'

You can use the following script (based upon your query):

`myscript.sql`:

```
TEE output.txt
SELECT 'STARTING the script...' AS '';
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT "', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, '" AS ', '""', '; ', 'SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ';') 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE 
  TABLE_NAME = 'm_appuser' AND 
  TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'mifostenant%'  
INTO OUTFILE 'query.txt';

SOURCE query.txt;
SELECT 'DONE.' AS '';
NOTEE
```

Run it from `mysql` client:

```
SOURCE myscript.sql;
```

This will create a result text file `"output.txt"`, similar to this:

```
+------------------------+
|                        |
+------------------------+
| STARTING the script... |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+------------------------+
|                        |
+------------------------+
| mifostenant1.m_appuser |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----+---------+
| c1  | c2      |
+-----+---------+
|   5 | five    |
|   4 | four    |
+-----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------------+
|                        |
+------------------------+
| mifostenant2.m_appuser |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----+---------+
| c1  | c2      |
+-----+---------+
|   1 | NULL    |
|   5 | five    |
|   4 | four    |
+-----+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+
|                      |
+----------------------+
| DONE.                |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```